# Custom domain for onelogin portal?

Tags: onelogin

Can you advise if OneLogin provides the ability to have a custom domain associated with the onelogin portal?

At present using a trial account, we see we can get

> `companyname`.onelogin.com

but we would like something like

> `login.companyname`.com

to be associated with OneLogin.

1. can you advise how do we configure the above setup? what is required in OneLogin configuration (and subscription) and what is required at our end (DNS config plus anything else)?
2. Not our preferred choice but there are some references that seem to infer that if we were to setup a site `login.companyname.com` ourselves, it might be possible to display the standard `companyname`.onelogin.com within a frame.  could you point us to the location where prerequisites for a such a setup are listed?  (outside of onelogin config, which we think is just a checkbox to disable headers to allow iframe to be possible)

Thanks